# Trying to show accepted and commited points on gridview, but parent Iteration points are always zero

Tags: extjs, rally, extjs4.2

Trying to show accepted and commited points on gridview, but parent Iteration points are always zero

[image]

This is what I am trying to do.

but as you can see the points for parent team is always zero.

Below is the data I am getting from 'IterationCumulativeFlowData' for each iteration.

[image]

`Accept: 0, Commit: 0` is for the parent team.
Any help on this, or any suggestions. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you hand-build your data because [CumulativeFlowData](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#CumulativeFlowData) object from which [IterationCumulativeFlowData](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/objectModel.sp#IterationCumulativeFlowData) object inherits does not have Accept and Commit attributes.
Moreover, there are no automatic rollups in iteration cumulative flow data from child iterations to parent iterations.

As a background,  data is stored for each day of the Iteraton and a corresponding state.
There is:

CumulativeFlowData object for Day 1 of Iteration for everything in the Defined state,

CumulativeFlowData object for Day 1 of Iteration for everything in the In-Progress state,

CumulativeFlowData object for Day 1 of Iteration for everything in the Completed state, and

CumulativeFlowData object for Day 1 of Iteration for everything in the Accepted state, and so on for every day of the Iteration.

The CumulativeFlowData object also stores the TotalToDo and TaskEstimateTotal for all work on the given day of the Iteration and the corresponding State.

But if the top Iteration in the parent project does not actually have any work items assigned to it then the data will show null.

Here is an example. Let's say I have parent iteration 15649272066 and child iteration 15649272070.

These are 8 day iterations: 2013-12-05 12:00:00 AM to 2013-12-12 11:59:59 PM.

For each day data is collected for "Defined", "In-Progress", "Completed" and "Accepted" state, so this query for parent iteration 5649272066 will return 32 results:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iterationcumulativeflowdata?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/15648960960&query=(IterationObjectID%20%3D%2015649272066)&fetch=true&pagesize=200
```

and a similar query for a child iteration 15649272070 returns 32 results:

```
https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iterationcumulativeflowdata?workspace=https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/15648960960&query=(IterationObjectID%20%3D%2015649272070)&fetch=true&pagesize=200
```

The last result of parent iteration query (for the last day and "Accepted" state) looks like this:

```
{

    _rallyAPIMajor: "2",
    _rallyAPIMinor: "0",
    _ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iterationcumulativeflowdata/15782599198",
    _refObjectUUID: "06f215bc-b84b-4c5d-bbf9-e1eb16b61159",
    _objectVersion: "1",
    CreationDate: "2013-12-11T17:00:00.000Z",
    _CreatedAt: "Dec 12, 2013",
    ObjectID: 15782599198,
    VersionId: "1",
    Subscription: {},
    Workspace: {},
    CardCount: 0,
    CardEstimateTotal: 0,
    CardState: "Accepted",
    CardToDoTotal: 0,
    TaskEstimateTotal: 0,
    IterationObjectID: 15649272066,
    _type: "IterationCumulativeFlowData"

}
```

The last result of child iteration query (for the last day and "Accepted" state) looks like this:

```
{

    _rallyAPIMajor: "2",
    _rallyAPIMinor: "0",
    _ref: "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/iterationcumulativeflowdata/15782599126",
    _refObjectUUID: "3918c1c6-21a9-457a-afe4-b65a4108f160",
    _objectVersion: "1",
    CreationDate: "2013-12-11T17:00:00.000Z",
    _CreatedAt: "Dec 12, 2013",
    ObjectID: 15782599126,
    VersionId: "1",
    Subscription: {},
    Workspace: {},
    CardCount: 1,
    CardEstimateTotal: 2,
    CardState: "Accepted",
    CardToDoTotal: 0,
    TaskEstimateTotal: 2,
    IterationObjectID: 15649272070,
    _type: "IterationCumulativeFlowData"

}
```

Notice that there is no rollup of data to the parent iteration, for example CardEstimateTotal in parent iteration result is 0, while in child iteration result it is 2.

I assume that in your app you stitch Iteration and IterationCumulativeFlowData together to arrive at your final json object. Some of this data is not going to roll up automatically and you need to calculate totals in the code.

To check your own data directly in the browser by hitting the IterationCumulativeFlowData endpoint use the examples above after replacing ObjectIDs in my environment with those from yours.

Comment: thanks nick..yes I hand-builded that data..thanks for useful info..now trying to calculate total for parent by adding its children data..